# Lefschetz theorem for the fundamental group of quasi-projective varieties over $\mathbb C$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $$ be a smooth quasi-projective variety of dimension at least 2. The following generalization of Lefschetz Theorem  is proved for instance by Hamm and Le dung Trang: if $H$ is a *general* hyperplane section, then (fixing $x\in H$), the homomorphism
$$\pi_1(H,x)\to \pi_1(X, x)$$
is surjective (moreover an isomorphism for $\dim X\geq 3$).

In the case of a smooth projective variety it is true that the above holds for *any* $H$.

My question is the following: for the case of a quasi-projective variety, does one have any result on the codimension of the open set of hyperplanes where the statement holds?

Comment: In general this will be codimension one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Let me expand the question: say that $X$ is an open set of a variety $V$ in $\mathbb P^n$, and we know the dimension of $V$ and the codimension of $X$ in $V$; is it known (and does it make sense to ask) wether the codimension of the open set of hyperplanes where the statement holds depends on these data?